# I want a method that accepts an array, low number, high number. and returns an array with only numbers in between that

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
  public static int [] filterRange(int [] array, int low, int high){
      int numbers = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          if (i <= high && i >= low){
              numbers ++; 
          }  
      }
      int array1 [] = new int [numbers]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          if (i <= high && i >= low){
              array1[i] = array[i];
          }
      }

      return array1;
  }
```

I'm trying to write a method that doesn't use any built in functions. It accepts an array of numbers, a low value , and a high value and returns a new array that has only the numbers in between  the high and low value, as well as the high and low value if applicable.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at Question_1.filterRange(Question_1.java:41)
at Question_1.main(Question_1.java:13)
```

This is the error message I'm getting.

Comment: use high-low to get the size of your new array. Allocate it. Use a loop iterated from low to high to copy values into the new array.

Comment: Sounds like what I think I have, unless I'm not understanding? numbers++ gives me the amount of numbers in between my range and new int [numbers] makes a blank array of that size, but the next part I can't get right.

Comment: No offset, array1[i] = array[i + low], my answer should make it clearer.

Comment: First of all, you should tag this with what _language_ this code is supposed to be in. Second of all, why are you using a _loop_ to count, when as deanosaur already said (well, almost) a simple _subtraction_ could give you the same info much easier?

Comment: I don't think the subtraction would would work to make the size of the array because the initial array may not necessarily be consecutive numbers. {1,5,7,9,1,2,4}

Comment: Wait a minute... Your code is slicing the array not filtering it. First loop should be checking array[i] against high and low if that's what you want to do!

Comment: you need to check if low < 0 and high > array.length.  Then, when you copy to values into the new array, the index i is NOT the same for both arrays. For example, if low=10, you'll be copying `newArray[0]=oldArray[10];`, so you need to either start looping at 10, or use two separate indices.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it now! :D

Answer (score 2):

Or in pseudo code

This is slicing i.e taking indexes low to high.

```
newSize = high - low + 1;
int array1 [] = new int [newSize]
for int i = 0; i < newSize; i++
  array1[i] = array[i + low]
```

This is selecting / filtering

Still in long hand, but I'm not a java boy.

```
  public static int [] filterRange(int [] array, int low, int high){
      int numbers = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          if (array[i] <= high && array[i] >= low){
              numbers ++; 
          }  
      }
      int array1 [] = new int [numbers]; 
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
          if (array[i] <= high && array[i] >= low){
              array1[index] = array[i];
          index++; // should be inside the if, I'm a twit
          }
      }

      return array1;
  }
```

I suggest you have a look at Lists in java, then you won't need to do it all twice. Not  a java boy but I'd be surprised if it doesn't have something like Ruby's

```
array1.select{|i| (i >= low) && (i <= high)}
```

Comment: Better use `System.arraycopy` it's much faster than a `for` loop

Comment: Well yes, but the OP seemed to want to to do it longhand. :)

Comment: Yeah to me this should work perfectly and I don't see why, but I'm still getting an out of bounds error

Answer (score 0):

If the high and low numbers are array index, Tony has already answered your question. If the high and low numbers are array values, please see code below.

```
public static int [] filterRange(int [] array, int low, int high){
  int[] array1 = new int[array.length];
  int numbers = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     ///// this is what you really mean, right?
       if (array[i] <= high && array[i] >= low){
           array1[numbers] = array[i];
           numbers ++; 
      }  
  }
  return Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, 0, numbers);
```

}

then you can use a for loop to output the result

```
int[] result = new int[numbers];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) result[i] = array1[i];
return result;
```

Comment: Yeah that gives out the right output but I want to do it long hand. Instead of using Arrays.copyOfRange.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty closer:

```
 public static int[] filterRange(int[] array, int low, int high){
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       if(array[i]>=low && array[i]<=high) size++;
    }
    int[] array1 = new int[size];
    for(int i=0, j=0; i< array.length; i++) {
       if(array[i]>=low && array[i]<=high) array1[j++] = array[i];
    }
    return array1;
 }
```

and just for yucks:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> filterRange(T[] array, T low, T high){
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int i=0, j=0; i< array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].compareTo(low)>=0 && array[i].compareTo(high)<=0) list.add(array[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as my first answer mate. Guy is filtering based on high and low not slicing.

Answer (score 0):

A quick implementation:

```
public static Integer[] filterRange(int[] array, int low, int high) {
    List<Integer> aux = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i : array) {
        if (i <= high && i >= low) {
            aux.add(i);
        }
    }
    return aux.toArray(new Integer[aux.size()]);
}
```